# How To Add Items From a ComboBox to a List Collection

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've got a combo box with a few strings. I would like to add those string to a List collection. Is this the correct way of doing it?

```
List<string> comboItems = new List<string>();

foreach(string passItems in comboEmail.Items)
{
    comboItems.Add(passItems);
}
```

Comment: does it work as expected?

Comment: @stefankmitph - Yes it does! However, is that the ideal way of dong it?

Comment: you want an elegant way to do it?

Comment: Yes, however, is the way I did okay/ideal?

Comment: What mean "ideal way"?

Comment: List<string> comboItems = new List<string>(comboEmail.Items);

Comment: Okay, is is the proper way of doing it? Are there better ways, could I run into potential problems doing it this way?

Comment: If you get a expecting result then use it until you run into problems

Comment: @DanielVorph that absolutely will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly different way:

```
List<string> comboItems = comboEmail.Items.Cast<string>().ToList();
```

Comment: @Fabio fair enough, mate... exact same way in one line :)

Comment: For running application this is a same way

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly valid approach.

You can also cast to string and use `AddRange` to create a one-liner.

```
comboItems.AddRange(cb.comboEmail.Cast<string>());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is simple enough. Use it.

Sometimes simple `foreach` statement with one line code inside
will be more readable then nice looking one line `LINQ` code.

Anyway both versions will be doing almost same work. `LINQ` can be even slowly then `foreach`